# Titanium Studio Installation - Not able to run Hello World program in Android EMULATOR

Tags: titanium

Not able to run my first application disappointing!

I have installed the required software from Titanium studio. Software installed are
JAVA JDK, NODE.JS, Android SDK,.. and the rest of Titanium tools.

After Android SDK installation successful.I tried creating a sample Hello world application and tried running in Android Emulator  received following error.

" --skip-js-minify was unexpected at this time.
C:\Users\AAA\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\myFirstApp>  "C:\Users\AAA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node.exe"  "C:\Users\AAA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\titanium\bin\titanium" --no-colors --no-progress-bars --no-prompt build --platform android --sdk 3.2.2.GA --log-level trace --target emulator --android-sdk C:\Users\AAA\Android.SDK --device-id "10.1" WXGA (Tablet)" --skip-js-minify
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 255

Not sure what is the problem tried re installing the studio No luck.

Thx
umral